# Function Template Instantiated With Runtime Constant

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, function-templates

I need some way to combine lambda's ability capture a runtime value and function template's ability to specify any type we want. What is the best way to do it?

Lambda allows us to capture the value of a local variable during runtime e.g.

```
unsigned char c=0;
auto compareEquality=[c](unsigned char c1) ->bool {return c1==c;};
..
scanner(compareEquality);
```

So `scanner` is passed a function that has runtime determined value 0 embeded, and inside `scanner` we call `compareEquality` passing it an `unsigned char` to compare against 0 or any other values obtained during runtime. But I also want the parameter to be of any type I want instead of just `unsigned char`. It would be nice to have this:

```
template<typename T>
bool compareEquality(T data) {
  return ( data== c);//error, what is 'c'?
}
```

But with function template, I cannot embed a runtime constant in it and just pass around the function like this:

```
scanner(compareEquality);
```

The above code doesn't allow me to specify what value to compare with inside the function.

What is the best way to combine function template and lambda's capture so that `compareEquality` can be passed around with some embedded runtime value while we don't have to define separate versions accepting different parameter types.

Comment: Have you tried to use `auto` type-deduction for your lambda arguments? As in `[c](auto c1) {return c1==c;}`

Comment: But with `[c](auto c1) {return c1==c;}`, does it mean we need to know  `c` is of type `unsigned char` when defining the lambda?

Comment: The type of `c` must be known for any lambda to be able to capture it. And as long as you can compare `c` and `c1` using `==`, then their actual types doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your question, but you could write a higher order function that returns a lambda:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
constexpr auto is_equal_to(T value)
{
    return [value](T const& x) { return x == value; };   
}

int main(void)
{
    std::vector src {17, 4, 42, 23, 9, 17, 8, 61};   
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "count (" << x << "): "
        << std::count_if(src.cbegin(), src.cend(), is_equal_to(x)) << '\n';

    std::cout << "count (42): "
        << std::count_if(src.cbegin(), src.cend(), is_equal_to(42)) << '\n';   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is having a function that builds those lambdas for you as in the following:

```
template<typename T>
auto ret_f(const T& p){
    return  [p](const T& p1)-> bool 
               {return p1==p;};
}
struct foo{
    int a;
    double b;
    bool c;

    bool operator==(const foo& f){
        return false;
    }
};

int main() { 
    unsigned char c= 0;
    int i = 0;
    foo bar {22,15.2,false};

    auto fchar = ret_f(c);
    auto fint = ret_f(i);    
    auto f_foo = ret_f(bar);

    cout<<fchar('a');

    cout<<fint(2.6);

    cout<<f_foo(bar);

return 0;
```

This way you can simply invoke `ret_f` with the right parameter and have the right lambda back.